# Phd Application follow up contact the lecturer or the school

Tags: application

After applied to a phd offer in a cluster group in Germany.
I've had a promising phone chat with one professor of the group.  Our research interests are closely related and he told me i will receive a mail from the administration not from him.
The interview went well, he was even querying about the visa procedure. But it's almost 20 days now and i did not received anything. I'm confused.
Should i contact him to ask? And what to write?  As he as warned me that the administration always took too much time.
And i do not have any contact with the administration since the beginning.

Answer (score 1):

I have been involved in multiple PhD student searchers. Things tend to be rather informal. If I were you I would send him an email inquiring about the status of the application. Keep in mind tho that sometimes things are slow in Academia.